# Experiment on a particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-technique

The solution of wave equation in a box gives some nodes where the wave is $0$ and there wouldn't be a particle present at any time. Did anyone confirmed that experimentally? By example one can send other particles in the nodes and check for their scattering. As far as I am acquainted I haven't seen such experiment. Have anyone know something? Or maybe any other idea for checking this.

Comment: The probability of finding the particle **in a single point** is in fact always $0$. That follows from the particle's *probability distribution* $|\psi(x)|^2$

Comment: Worth reading: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127334/

Comment: Do you think that the box has some special role here except for providing such boundary conditions that produce nodes in its stationary states? If not, then your question reduces to whether it has been verified that a particle is never detected at a node of a wavefuction. This can be verified in a simple double slit experiment where you see that no particles are detected at the final screen at locations where the wavefuction has nodes.

Comment: @Gert what you want to say? Modul Psi(x) squared is exactly the probability to find the particle in point x. When it is bigger than 0 you surely will register a particle. E.g. when in the double slit psi (x) is not zero you get particles detected.

Comment: @DvijD.C. in the double slit there still exist trajectories where the particle can pass (there was an experiment Sascha Kohen et. al. maybe 2012 AFAIR). But in the box there wouldn't be any. The particle (if such thing exists) must jump tru that point with infinitesimal speed. I wonder why one should deny a possible experiment on the basis of other similar situation based on theory. It would be not easy caring this experiment?

Comment: @Mercury *Modul Psi(x) squared is exactly the probability to find the particle in point x.* No, it's not. It's the **probability density**. Please read the link I provided.

Comment: @Mercury I don't get your point, are you saying that there are some particles detected at the nodes of the wave function on the final screen? I can imagine that for various reasons, namely, you can never measure the position precisely (an eigenstate of the position operator is not normalizable) and, of course, there are further uncertainties coming from the measurement apparatus. However, such factors would also be present in the case of the box. I don't see why the box case would give you a cleaner situation than double-slit. And no, I am not saying that people should only do one experiment.

Comment: No. I am saying that the particle can circumvent the 0 points. I am sorry about the name of paper. It is Sacha Cocsis et al. Observing the Average Trajectories of Single Photons in a Two-Slit Interferometer.

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward confirmation comes from electron capture decay. There, the atomic electrons are particles in a box, where the potential comes from their binding to the nucleus. Electrons capture und protons in the nucleus to form neutrons and neutrinos. Electron capture decays happen mostly throught K shell electrons, since these have a non-zero probability distribution at the origin. In contrast, L shell electrons rarely get captured due to their orbitals having zero probability distribution at the origin (which is where the nucleus sits).

Comment: Well that is a nice example. But there is a path for the electron to go around the nuclei which is not broken. In the case of a box there is a whole plane where the particle can not pass as a particle but only as wave. If an experiment is carried out for the box that would probably mean that there are not particles in reality at all but just that particles are emergent phenomena from interaction of fields. That's why I think that such experiment is very important and wonder why it is not carried out. Maybe it is not possible for technical reasons?

Comment: The typical intro example "particle in a box" is one-dimensional

Comment: Maybe. But if the box is 3 dimensional there are unbroken planes of 0 probability. If z=0 is the plane of the wall every x,y from it which starts a 1d wave forms a standing wave and each wave has the same form as the others. So they all have nodes in 1 plane.

Comment: No. The electron orbitals are exactly the solutions to the particle in a box in 3D. The intersection of three plane nodes is just a point.

Comment: That's very surprising for me. I think the electron orbitals should be solutions to a particle in a spherical box not rectangular box. To mimic a rectangular box there must be a plane of nucleis in the central plane but this also will be an approximation.

Comment: Both spherical and cubic boxes have the same boundary condition for the wavefunction everywhere on the surface

Comment: Well but imaging classical trajectories in a spherical box if not passing exactly mathematically through the center of the sphere the particle would deflect and not going back the same path and not have nods and would not be 1D. Where in a ideal rectangular box the particle should return exactly on the same path and stay 1D.

Comment: In fact all particles entering in a rectangular box can be made to move perpendicular to the entrance wall and all will move in 1D for themselves. For the L electrons there is from Bohm point of view clear paths not to pass through the center. I don't think one can get a solution in a rectangular box which looks like L orbitals in atoms.